# AutoSizing of Usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, autosize

For a WPF application I have a user control MyUsrCntrl with Height=300 and Width=300 
When i place MyUsrCntrl in a window and set its size to 600x600 the user control get resized but the controls in that does not get resized ,
is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extend and compress the height and Width of your Usercontrol then make the Parent Controls `Height="*"` and `Width="*"` and don't assign any height and width to your controls present inside UserControl. Something like:

```
<Grid Margin="4" Background="Orange">    
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>    
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">    
        <TextBlock Text="It is fixed" Margin="1"/>       
        <Button Content="It is fixed"/>    
    </StackPanel>    
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">    
        <TextBlock Text="It is variable" Margin="1"/>    
        <Button Content="It is fixed" Margin="2"/>    
    </StackPanel>    
</Grid>
```

Comment: Happy to help always sir, have fun